# Material transition in java does not work

Tags: java, android, material-design

android studio show me this error why? i saw documentation and other issues here and they no have problem whit implementing MaterialContainerTransform in setSharedElementEnterTransition...

here are an image of the error: [issue transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63NuW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As document from google stated that you need to import for shared element between Activity

```
 import com.google.android.material.transition.platform.MaterialContainerTransform
```

Reference: https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion/

Comment: Wow, just an import, I have to be more careful with this, thank you so much!